# Why isn't my new class added to the database schema with Entity Framework after I add a migration?

Tags: entity-framework

Is there any good reason why after I create a new class in my Models folder, called : City

```
public class City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and then I run the command in Package Console:
`Add-Migration migration3`

and then: `Update-Database`

...My new entity (City) does not generate a table called City in the database with Entity Framework (Code first approach)?

I already had two other entities:

```
public class Restaurant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
```

and :

```
public class RestaurantReview
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
    }
```

## By the way, the migy autogenerated just has an empty Up and Down method. Please advise.

By the way, after I changed City to CityId (property name) inside Restaurant class, EF recorded this property name change in a migration file (I did a `Add-Migration migz`). But the City entity still didn't get recorded in a migration file with all its properties, even though it's a new entity. Why?

Comment: you do add `DbSet<>` in your context?

Comment: That was it. I totally had forgotten thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must do add `DbSet<T>` in your DbContext like this:

```
public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants {get; set;}
```